# Minifilter redirect file creation in pre operation?

Tags: c++, driver, minifilter, windows-kernel, kernel-mode

I am trying to redirect file creation on a volume of hard disk (i.e \Device\HarddiskVolume2)

I found [redirecting file name in minifilter open pre](http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=139332). But I got a system dialog as below

[image]

Here is my code:

```
// I tested with pFileName = &Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName;
// It has same result
pFileName = &FltObjects->FileObject->FileName;
if (pFileName->Buffer != NULL)
    ExFreePool(pFileName->Buffer);

// gRedirectFullFilePath is \\Device\\HarddiskVolume2\\File.ext
pFileName->Length = gRedirectFullFilePath.Length;
pFileName->MaximumLength = pFileName->Length;
pFileName->Buffer = (PWCH) ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, pFileName->MaximumLength);
if (pFileName->Buffer == NULL)
    goto PreOperationCleanup;

RtlCopyUnicodeString(pFileName, &gRedirectFullFilePath);

// Change I/O status
Data->IoStatus.Information = IO_REPARSE;
Data->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_REPARSE;
Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->RelatedFileObject = NULL;

FltSetCallbackDataDirty(Data);

return FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE;
```

I want this dialog to be not show. How should I do?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Verify you have specified the volume path appropriately.

Comment: @Rohan I get `gRedirectFullFilePath` from `InstanceSetup` routine. If file.ext exist or not, the dialog always show when I drag & drop to this volume.

Answer (score 1):

You should check [SimRep File System Minifilter Driver](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/SimRep-File-System-9a4e2206) example from WDK8.1 samples.

For example it ignores volume opens (*FO_VOLUME_OPEN*) and directory opens (*SL_OPEN_TARGET_DIRECTORY*). Maybe that is causing troubles to you.
It also uses `IoReplaceFileObjectName` to replace name of a file object (should be safer than direct changing of *FILE_OBJECT*).